# How do I type-hint OpenCV images in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-typing

I get that in Python OpenCV images are numpy arrays, that correspond to cv::Mat in c++.

This question is about what type-hint to put into python functions to properly restrict for OpenCV images (maybe even for a specific kind of OpenCV image).

What I do now is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

Mat = np.ndarray

def my_fun(image: Mat):
    cv2.imshow('display', image)
    cv2.waitKey()
```

Is there any better way to add typing information for OpenCV images in python?

Comment: is this about type hinting in python? specify these things to be numpy arrays. they _are_ regular numpy arrays. -- opencv will choke on some specific things numpy allows but cv::Mat doesn't, but there's probably no way (nor should there be) to make "static typing" check that... because python doesn't have static typing, it has programming-time, explicitly-executed "linting" for this (mypy etc).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes it is about properly type hinting the numpy arrays corresponding to cv::Mat. (not numpy arrays in general)

Comment: the python bindings of OpenCV don't have special arrays. it's all numpy, and during the call, that is mapped to a cv::Mat or std::vector or whatever is required. so... this kinda _is_ about type-hinting numpy arrays in general. there's nothing "special" to be done for opencv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify it as `numpy.typing.NDArray` with an entry type. For example,

```
import numpy as np

Mat = np.typing.NDArray[np.uint8]

def my_fun(img: Mat):
    pass
```

Comment: wow, this is a cool solution, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Another option if you don't want or need to be explicit with the underlying data-types is using the built-in typing stubs under the `cv2.typing` module.

```
from cv2.typing import MatLike

def my_fun(img: MatLike):
    pass
```

Additional typing stubs can be found on the project's source code here:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/python/src2/typing_stubs_generation/predefined_types.py